# Visual Studio creating blank aspx:1 files

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I'm currently using VS Community 2013 but I've seen this behaviour in previous versions of VS.

Scenario: I have previously saved and closed a solution whilst it has several tabs open. I then re-open the solution. The open tabs reload, but (as far as I can tell randomly) one or more of the aspx files that were open when I last saved and closed the solution, are recreated as a blank file with the extension aspx:1 or aspx:2.

Closing the blank file & reopening that file from the Solution Explorer restores the correct version of the file. No work is lost, so I admit this is an irritation rather than a crisis.

What's going on, and more importantly any idea how I can make it stop? I have got the Preview Tab functionality (Options >> Environment >> Tabs and Windows) turned off. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://ambracode.com/index/show/161001
it says there:
"It's the naming convention for Visual Studio when the window is cloned. Sometimes, however, Visual Studio just gets confused and names it that way."

Comment: Thanks for responding but that doesn't answer the question as to why they are blank, or indeed how I stop it.

Comment: I face OP's problem very often, but the aspx:1 or aspx:2 have it content keep original (not blank), and when I click at your link it redirect to other ads site.